# Eclipse AVD gives error of 'Unfortunately, (app) has stopped'

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, logcat

I am a beginning in trying to create applications for android using Eclipse (also why i didn't do pictures). I started to learn to program by following [Site (link)](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html). I tried this 3 times and each times it creates 2 projects. First one always called 'appcompat_v7' and the second one what ever i called it. In this instance I called it 'FirstApp'. In the project FirstApp, I could not find /res/layout containing anything so i created it, calling it fragment_main.xml. Containing:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I edited my 'androidmanifest.xml' to say:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.firstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And my strings.xml says:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">FirstApp</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
</resources>
```

When running on my Samsung Galaxy S4 or on a AVD manager:

> (settings are platform: 4.4W , API Lvl: 20 , and CPU/ABI: Android Wear
> ARM (armeabi-v7a) , Device: Nexus 5)

Both give me the same error. "Unfortunately, (app name) has stopped."

And my LogCat gives me this log:

> ~Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
>
> ~Shutting down VM
>
> ~threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2aa9d70)
>
> ~FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> ~Process: com.example.firstapp, PID: 745
>
> ~java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentI
> nfo{com.example.firstapp/com.example.firstapp.MainActivity}: java.lan
> g.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.firstapp.Mai
> nActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.firs
> tapp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.firs
> tapp-2, /system/lib]]
>
> ~at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2123)
>
> ~at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
>
> ~at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
>
> ~at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
>
> ~at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
> ~at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>
> ~at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
>
> ~at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> ~at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>
> ~at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
>
> ~at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
>
> ~at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> ~Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.e
> xample.firstapp.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/a
> pp/com.example.firstapp-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-l
> ib/com.example.firstapp-2, /system/lib]]
>
> ~at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>
> ~at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
>
> ~at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
>
> ~at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
>
> ~at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
>
> ~ ... 11 more
>
> ~Sending signal. PID: 745 SIG: 9

I have not edited anything else, but those xml files (strings.xml, fragment_main.xml, and AndroidManifest.xml)
Here is a pic of my packages:
[image]

Please help to remove this error. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried removing the `.` before `MainActivity` in the manifest? Do you actually have a class called `com.example.firstapp.MainActivity`?

Comment: I tried removing the '.' and it still gave me the error. When I was creating my project 'com.example.firstapp' was what the package name defaulted to, while naming it. And later while creating the project the default of Activity Name is 'MainActivity'. I assumed that was what the class or something I should refer too (I might be wrong). @BevynQ

Comment: Why are you using fragments if you only have a MainActivity?

Comment: The website I was using told me to name it that. @StephanBranczyk

Comment: Show us your MainActivity java code and tell us in which file that that class is located in?

Comment: I do not have any file named MainActivity. I took a picture of my files. My only things I wrote are strings, AndroidManifest and fragemnt_main. I think part of my problem is I don't know what to put where the 'MainActivity' is. @StephanBranczyk

Comment: expand `com.example.firstapp` and u will see there is a class named `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the reason that your app is creating two projects is for compatibility with devices running below API 14. I would recommend (and this is just a personal preference) that, as a beginner, when you create your projects you should set the minimum API level to 14.

When setting up a new project, check the check box that says 'Create activity', right under 'Create custom launcher icon':

[image]

Among the automatically created files, you should find a **MainActivity.java** file (in src > com.example.YourAppName) and an **activity_main.xml** layout file (in res > layout). If they are not created, this points to issues with your Eclipse/ADT/SDK setup.

So my advice would be to create a new project (above API 14) and run it without editing/creating any files. If it works, then you're good to go.